# Kubernetes : How to assign static IP address or HostName to node and POD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

We have a setup where we want to run 3 replicas of our Image. Each replica will be run in independent node and corresponding pods inside it.
So to summarize we will have 3 nodes in 3 separate JVMs and 3 corresponding pods.
Please provide following details,

1. Can we fix POD IP and hostName always?
2. Can the Node IP and hostname be same as machine IP and hostname?
3. Can the same Machine IP and hostname be made POD IP and hostname?

Comment: If that's your requirements, you might find it easier to not use Kubernetes and to run the application directly on the nodes.  Kubernetes has its own networking layer (see for example the Kubernetes documentation on in-cluster [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)) and you don't typically try to fix a pod to a specific node.

Comment: @DavidMaze, In our setup it would be 3 different JVMs, where each JVM will have a single node and a single pod associated with it(3 replicas in 3 individual nodes and JVM). So when we have a fixed JVM/System name, we were thinking of fixing the IP:PORT for each pod so that communication to respective pods would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

`Can we fix POD IP and hostName always?`

There is a `hostname` field for Pod that you can use. Using static IP for Pod is possible if the CNI plugin that you used support it. For example, Calico does [support](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/networking/use-specific-ip) this use case. You need to check your CNI manual.

`Can the Node IP and hostname be same as machine IP and hostname?`

Yes.

`Can the same Machine IP and hostname be made POD IP and hostname?`

Pod name is up to you to set, but Pod IP is always in the range of Pod CIDR which is not applicable to machine IP.

Comment: Can we fix POD IP and hostName always? >>> Thanks, so it depends on CNI Plugin.                    Can the Node IP and hostname be same as machine IP and hostname? Yes >>>Can you direct me to setting documentation?